# how to add new values to cells on xlsx file with node js

Tags: node.js, xlsx, sheetjs

I read a xlsx file with 7 column, it has headers between the range A4 to G4. I want to add values of strings to each column using a loop . the problem when the file contains data in it nothing is printed inside the file, but if I have added some values it will append the values and ignore the empty cells. I want to be able to decide the range and add as many values as I could even on the empty cells. for example the file contains 9 filled rows with strings if i decided to go append 20 rows it wont work only 9 will be append on the xlsx sheet

my code read a file and update the contents on a new xlsx sheet file.

```
   var xlsx = require("xlsx");
   var workBook = xlsx.readFile("TestSheet.xlsx");
   var workSheet = workBook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
 
   var range = {s:{c:0, r:1}, e:{c:7, r:20}};//assign the range

      for(var R = range.s.r; R <= range.e.r; R++) {
       for(var C = range.s.c; C <= range.e.c; C++) {
      
      /* if an A1-style address is needed, encode the address */
       var cell_ref = xlsx.utils.encode_cell({c:C, r:R});

       workSheet[cell_ref.toString()] =  { t: 's', v: 'Nike'};
      
       console.log(cell_ref + " " + workSheet[cell_ref].v );
       }
     }
  
  var newBook = xlsx.utils.book_new();

  xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(newBook, workSheet, "Sheet2");
  xlsx.writeFile(newBook, "newOutput.xlsx");
```

the compile printout

PS D:\CT2> node main.js
A5 Nice
B5 Nice
C5 Nice
D5 Nice
E5 Nice
F5 Nice
G5 Nice
H5 Nice
A6 Nice
B6 Nice
C6 Nice
D6 Nice
E6 Nice
F6 Nice
G6 Nice
H6 Nice
A7 Nice
B7 Nice
C7 Nice
D7 Nice
E7 Nice
F7 Nice
G7 Nice
H7 Nice
A8 Nice
B8 Nice
C8 Nice
D8 Nice
E8 Nice
F8 Nice
G8 Nice
H8 Nice
A9 Nice
B9 Nice
C9 Nice
D9 Nice
E9 Nice
F9 Nice
G9 Nice
H9 Nice
A10 Nice
B10 Nice
C10 Nice
D10 Nice
E10 Nice
F10 Nice
G10 Nice
H10 Nice
A11 Nice
B11 Nice
C11 Nice
D11 Nice
E11 Nice
F11 Nice
G11 Nice
H11 Nice
A12 Nice
B12 Nice
C12 Nice
D12 Nice
E12 Nice
F12 Nice
G12 Nice
H12 Nice
A13 Nice
B13 Nice
C13 Nice
D13 Nice
E13 Nice
F13 Nice
G13 Nice
H13 Nice
A14 Nice
B14 Nice
C14 Nice
D14 Nice
E14 Nice
F14 Nice
G14 Nice
H14 Nice
A15 Nice
B15 Nice
C15 Nice
D15 Nice
E15 Nice
F15 Nice
G15 Nice
H15 Nice
A16 Nice
B16 Nice
C16 Nice
D16 Nice
E16 Nice
F16 Nice
G16 Nice
H16 Nice
A17 Nice
B17 Nice
C17 Nice
D17 Nice
E17 Nice
F17 Nice
G17 Nice
H17 Nice
A18 Nice
B18 Nice
C18 Nice
D18 Nice
E18 Nice
F18 Nice
G18 Nice
H18 Nice
A19 Nice
B19 Nice
C19 Nice
D19 Nice
E19 Nice
F19 Nice
G19 Nice
H19 Nice
A20 Nice
B20 Nice
C20 Nice
D20 Nice
E20 Nice
F20 Nice
G20 Nice
H20 Nice
A21 Nice
B21 Nice
C21 Nice
D21 Nice
E21 Nice
F21 Nice
G21 Nice
H21 Nice

but in the xlsx sheet it doesn't show any results only 9 rows not the rest.

Comment: Are you sure that your version supports edits to files? Also it seems that you are not "appending" rows, but rather over writing the first 20 rows, so it would seem that you are not able to maky any changes to the file.

Comment: yes it edits, your suggestion is true but how to append then?